# local variable 'boolean' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, global-variables

I'm trying to set boolean value False, actually the class will run many times, but i want the state of boolean to be true in the first iteration and false state for the rest of iterations.

Tried many things, sometimes name not defined error.

```
global boolean
boolean = True
class class_name():
        if boolean is True:
            web_check = '1'
            loc_check = '2'
            sof_check = '3'
            boolean = False
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You're using it inside a class and outside of any function anyway, what is it you're trying to do? why do you need a global?

Comment: Can you give us an example implementation of the class being called?

Comment: I thought global variable would, I just want 'web_check = '1', loc_check = ', sof_check = '3' values to defined only once and not change their values for other iterations

Comment: It's scrapy spider, it runs many times for different links.

Comment: Works for me without raising exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried declaring it inside the class?

```
boolean = True
class class_name():
        global boolean
        if boolean is True:
            web_check = '1'
            loc_check = '2'
            sof_check = '3'
            boolean = False
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much, it works. Can you explain me a bit about the logic?

Comment: Think of classes, definitions, functions as closed circuits. You use global kind of like a plugin to existing variables out side the circuit.